# Ruby on rails get last record from result set

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, record

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
            :adapter => "mysql2",
            :host => "localhost",
            :database => "siteconfig_development",
            :username => "root",
            :password => "root123"
)

sql = 'SELECT * from users'

@success_data = @connection.connection.execute(sql);
```

How to get last record from @success_data without iterating it?

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM users
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
fetch last record from the database is a sol.

Comment: I need to pull all users but need value of last record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
  @success_data = @connection.connection.select_all(sql);
  @success_data.class  
  => Array
```

you could use any array method on `@success_data`

```
  @success_data.last  # will return the last element
```

or

```
  @success_data[-1]   # will return the last element
```

Comment: my need is to get all users but require value of last record.

Comment: @success_data is not an array but returns <Mysql2::Result:0x00000001a5ed70>

Answer (score 1):

sql = 'SELECT * from users order by id desc limit 1'

Comment: I have to pull all users, but before iteration i need to fetch the field of last record... so above query will not solve purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do `.last` on collections but what you're doing here is a bit off the rails path, is this the default way you access your database or is this a special case?

Comment: No, this is a special case. I have to create stand alone script that needs to interact with database.

Comment: I used .last but got error undefined method `last' for #<Mysql2::Result:0x00000001a5ed70>